# MPI double rings, max, min and average

Tags: c++, mpi

We only have been working on MPI for about one day in my computer programming class, and I now have to write a program for it. I am to write a program that organizes processes into two rings.

The first ring begins with process 0 and proceeds to send a message to the next even process and the last process sending its message back to process 0. For example, 0--> 2 --> 4 --> 6 --> 8 --> 0 (but it goes all the way up to 32 instead of 8). The next ring is the same, but begins with process 1 and sends to the previous off process and then back to 1. For example,  1--> 9--> 7--> 5 --> 3--> 1.

Also, I am supposed to find the max, min, and average of a very large array of integer numbers. I will have to scatter the array into pieces to each process, have each process compute a partial answer, and then reduce back the answer together on process 0 after everyone is done.

Finally, I am to scatter across the processes and each process will have to count how many of each letter appears in a section. That part really makes no sense to me. But we have just learned the very basics, so no fancy stuff please! Here's what I have so far, I have commented out some things to just remind myself of some stuff, so please ignore if necessary.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"

using namespace std;
// compile: mpicxx program.cpp
 // run: mpirun -np 4 ./a.out 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int rank;       // unique number associated with each core
int size;       // total number of cores
char message[80];
char recvd[80];
int prev_node, next_node;
int tag;
MPI_Status status;
// start MPI interface
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

sprintf(message, "Heeeelp! from %d", rank);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
next_node = (rank + 2) % size;
prev_node = (size + rank - 2) % size;


tag = 0;
if (rank % 2) {
    MPI_Send(&message, 80, MPI_CHAR, prev_node, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Recv(&recvd, 80, MPI_CHAR, next_node, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
} else {
    MPI_Send(&message, 80, MPI_CHAR, next_node, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Recv(&recvd, 80, MPI_CHAR, prev_node, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}

cout << "* Rank " << rank << ": " << recvd << endl;

//max
int large_array[100];

rank == 0;  
int max = 0;

MPI_Scatter(&large_array, 1, MPI_INT, large_array, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Reduce(&message, max, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


MPI_Finalize();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Are you stuck on anything specific?

Comment: I just don't really understand it honestly. The answer below helped a lot, but I am still not getting it to go from 0 to 2 to.... back to 0. I get 0 to 1 to 2....it's very frustrating because it's hard for me to even read the program.

Answer (score 5):

I have a small suggestion about this:

```
dest = rank + 2;
if (rank == size - 1)
    dest = 0;
source = rank - 2;
if (rank == 0)
    source = size - 1;
```

I think `dest` and `source`, as names, are going to be confusing (as *both* are destinations of messages, depending on the value of `rank`). Using the `%` operator might help improve clarity:

```
next_node = (rank + 2) % size;
prev_node = (size + rank - 2) % size;
```

You can select whether to receive or send to `next_node` and `prev_node` based on the value of `rank % 2`:

```
if (rank % 2) {
        MPI_Send(&message, 80, MPI_CHAR, prev_node, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&message, 80, MPI_CHAR, next_node, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
} else {
        MPI_Send(&message, 80, MPI_CHAR, next_node, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&message, 80, MPI_CHAR, prev_node, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
```

Doing this once or twice is fine, but if you find your code *littered* with these sorts of switches, it'd make sense to place these ring routines in a function and pass in the next and previous nodes as parameters.

When it comes time to distribute your arrays of numbers and arrays of characters, keep in mind that `n / size` will leave a remainder of `n % size` elements at the end of your array that also need to be handled. (Probably on the master node, just for simplicity.)

I added a few more output statements (and a place to store the message from the other nodes) and the simple rings program works as expected:

```
$ mpirun -np 16 ./a.out | sort -k3n
* Rank 0: Heeeelp! from 14
* Rank 1: Heeeelp! from 3
* Rank 2: Heeeelp! from 0
* Rank 3: Heeeelp! from 5
* Rank 4: Heeeelp! from 2
* Rank 5: Heeeelp! from 7
* Rank 6: Heeeelp! from 4
* Rank 7: Heeeelp! from 9
* Rank 8: Heeeelp! from 6
* Rank 9: Heeeelp! from 11
* Rank 10: Heeeelp! from 8
* Rank 11: Heeeelp! from 13
* Rank 12: Heeeelp! from 10
* Rank 13: Heeeelp! from 15
* Rank 14: Heeeelp! from 12
* Rank 15: Heeeelp! from 1
```

You can see the two rings there, each in their own direction:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"

using namespace std;
// compile: mpicxx program.cpp
// run: mpirun -np 4 ./a.out 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank;       // unique number associated with each core
    int size;       // total number of cores
    char message[80];
    char recvd[80];
    int prev_node, next_node;
    int tag;
    MPI_Status status;
    // start MPI interface
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    sprintf(message, "Heeeelp! from %d", rank);

    // cout << "Rank " << rank << ": " << message << endl;

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    next_node = (rank + 2) % size;
    prev_node = (size + rank - 2) % size;


    tag = 0;
    if (rank % 2) {
        MPI_Send(&message, 80, MPI_CHAR, prev_node, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&recvd, 80, MPI_CHAR, next_node, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    } else {
        MPI_Send(&message, 80, MPI_CHAR, next_node, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&recvd, 80, MPI_CHAR, prev_node, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }

    cout << "* Rank " << rank << ": " << recvd << endl;

    //cout << "After - Rank " << rank << ": " << message << endl;
    // end MPI interface
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

When it comes time to write the larger programs (array min, max, avg, and word counts), you'll need to change things slightly: only `rank == 0` will be sending messages at the start; it will send to all the other processes their pieces of the puzzle. All the other processes will receive, do the work, then send back the results. `rank == 0` will then need to integrate the results from all of them into a coherent single answer.

Comment: @Alyssa, I put the pieces together into a whole program and fiddled with the message receiving too (each was overwriting its own message with the next message in the group). I hope this helps.

Comment: I edited the program above and tried to put the max array in. I have a little bit started, but I am unsure of how to get it to actually do that maximum. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: @Alyssa, it would probably be best to post a _new_ question with your attempt to get the min/max/avg working; these questions tend to work better with one specific problem at a time. Do you need to have a master process distribute the array? Or is it fine for each process to just _have_ its portion of the array? Do you have the processes sending their results back to the lead process yet? (Do they need to?)